# display high resolution image memory error

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I tried displaying a 1080x600 png in a splash screen activity and i got and OutOfMemoryError at BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (decodeStream).

so I decided to calculate the InSampleSize before decoding the resource using this method :

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

and this worked for 480x800, 720x1280, 1080x1920 without errors, but when i opened it in my friends nexus 5 (1080x1920) it crashed because it loaded the png with it real dimensions.

so now i'm confused and can't think of a better way to do it without ruining the quality of the picture for high resolution phones.

Comment: put your drawables in to drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: have you tried 9 patch or a vector drawable??

Comment: I do not need such a big png for a splash screen, you can use `fitXY` for the `ImageView` and `RGB_565` for option, and use a small png.